# Audio Recording with Callback method

Tags: tizen

I am new at Tizen Platform. I was trying to record audio through Samsung Galaxy Watch 2 which has Tizen 4.0 SDK. I can perform the audio recording. But it only writes the whole audio data into a file at the end of the recording when I stop the recorder. I have followed this instruction from Tizen SDK:
[Media Recording][1]
[1]: https://docs.tizen.org/application/native/guides/multimedia/media-recording/

But I need a callback method where it will give me the chunk of byte data while I am recording, not at the end of the recording when I stopped. Is it possible? Because I didn't find any solution for that through out the whole Tizen SDK documentation. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please check below APIs. The callback will be invoked while recording in real time.

1. PCM data stream callback : recorder_set_audio_stream_cb()
   https://docs.tizen.org/application/native/api/wearable/4.0/group__CAPI__MEDIA__RECORDER__MODULE.html#gaee86652361db0e93774f409df8654156
2. Encoded and muxed data stream callback : recorder_set_muxed_stream_cb()
   https://docs.tizen.org/application/native/api/wearable/4.0/group__CAPI__MEDIA__RECORDER__MODULE.html#ga15a44a05a818f1cdd116ca86f3629f7b

Comment: I tried that. It gives you those chunk of bytes right after you stop the recording. It does not give that while you are recording.